# create the table in aws athena from s3 bucket .csv file with help of glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

As i am new to AWS services, Actually i am trying to create the athena table from s3 bucket .csv file and also created the crawler for that. In my Csv file originally i have the below input data.

```
   name               designation    zip code    build no  address

 1  siddarth,james     professor      522135       3        mla colony
 2 roy,deshmukh       software       412230       1       sez apartments
 3  viliam,mckesson    accountant     628139       10      oakland road
```

after creating the table in athena, i am getting below output.

```
  name         designation     zip_code     build_no    address

1 siddarth     james          professor     
2  roy          deshmukh       software      
3 viliam       mckesson       contractor
```

As data is not populating as proper format data whatever csv file i have. but my required output should be like :

```
   name               designation    zip code    build no  address

   siddarth,james     professor      522135       3        mla colony
   roy,deshmukh       software       412230       1       sez apartments
   viliam,mckesson    accountant     628139       10      oakland road
```

Could anyone help for to create the table in athena by using the s3 bucket .csv file format data.

Answer (score 0):

Could you provide a plain text example line of your CSV? What's shown above are certainly not valid comma separated values and it's hard to give advice based on that.

Anyways, it looks like your first column contains commas. So it's all about how your values are quoted / special characters are escaped in order to be processed correctly.

Have a look at `OpenCSVSerDe` and respective documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/csv-serde.html). This should help...

Comment: I added the content of csv file. Could please help for that

Comment: @user98 the above is certainly not the plain content of a csv. please use a text editor to copy-paste the data (and make sure to redact any PII)

Comment: As of now That is only the .csv file i have.

Comment: I don't have original file. That is file i have in s3 bucket

Comment: the above looks like you've opened the csv in excel or something similar. that's pointless because all the necessary details are lost. just open it in a text editor

Comment: Is this way correct , can i convert to text file and import to athena